# Download file when hit in the browser's url

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I currently have a link to pdf and doc which is hosted on my server. Using selenium i opened headless chrome and hit the docx link and the document got downloaded **but pdf is not getting downloaded**..reason being pdf is being viewed in the browser instead of getting downloaded.

Example :- When you [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGyFt.jpg) this link. you can view the image.

Is there any attribute kind of parameter which i can append to the url and the pdf (or) image gets downloaded?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you asks: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: not this... this is programmatic.... i am referring to browser hit

Comment: This is happening due to the way Chrome behaves. You'll need to find a way to configure Chrome to behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is modify the browser settings first to force PDF downloads, for instance by opening `chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments` and then pressing the `#knob` button to activate this setting.

That I assume you're using Chrome obviously but there may be analogous settings in other browsers.